# MVC 4 error in accessing resource file from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, resources, embedded-resource

Getting error in accessing resource file string from MVC controller(working file with views)

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "TempNameSpace.App_GlobalResources.Resource_EN_US.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "TempNameSpace" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

**What I have already done**
1. Resource file build action : from content to Embedded resource
   
Result : Publish does not include resource files in it.
2. Added new resource file with name Resource.resx

Result : Same error

**Solution hierarchy**
1. Solution contains 4 projects, two with resource files(Resource.resx and Resource_EN_US under App_GlobalResources folder)
2. Designer for Resource_EN_US  contains correct namespace

```
global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("TempNameSpace.App_GlobalResources.Resource_EN_US", typeof(Resource_EN_US).Assembly);
```

Comment: Have you changed the *Access Modifier* to Public in all resource files?

Comment: Yes, I can access the resource file string  with @Resources.Resource_EN_US.WaterMarkEmail on views

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I use a seperate project for resources. I have set all resource files **Build Action** property to *Embedded Resource*.
On the reference to the resources project, I have **Copy Local** set to True for the resources project. (Rightclick a reference and select *Properties*)

If you have your resource files inside your web project, I think that the property corresponding with *Copy Local* should be **Copy to Output Directory** (Also accessible via rightclick and *Properties*).

**Edit:**
I see that in your comment you said that you access the file as **Resource.Resource_EN_US.WaterMarkEmail** but this is not the right way to access the files. You should access them as one single file: Resources.*Property*.
My files are named as: *Standard.resx*, *Standard.en.resx*, *Standard.no.resx* and so on. To access them I can use **Standard.*Property***. The resource files will mold toghether, but only if you give them valid names. If you can access all your resource files individually, then you have not used the correct naming convention.

I recommend implementing a ResourceHelper that uses the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access the property that you need.

Comment: Right Binke, we are not using the correct naming conventions because this has been implemented that way before, and now I don't want to change much, but yes that needs to done and I'll work on it soon.